# how to add <div> tag instead of <li>

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

forms.py

```
class TypeSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    checkbox_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label="", required=False)

def __init__(self, type_id, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TypeSelectionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    _type_checkbox = self.fields['checkbox_field']       
    MY_CHOICES=((type.id, type.title) for type in type)
    _type_checkbox.choices = MY_CHOICES
    initial_val = []
    type_selection = Types.objects.filter(parent_type_id=type_id,is_active=True)
    for type_selection in type_selection:
        initial_val.append(type_selection.id)
    _type_checkbox.initial = initial_val
```

views.py

```
def types(method):
    """"""""""""
    types = TypeSelectionForm(type_id)
    return render(request,'types.html',{'types':types})
```

In template I'm rendering the field like this,

types.html

```
    {% for field in types.checkbox_field %}                                 
     <div class="deletelist">
     {{field}}<br />
    </div>
   {% endfor %}
```

It is producing the html like this,

```
<ul>
<li><label for="id_checkbox_field_0"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="checkbox_field" value="597" id="id_checkbox_field_0" /> comp lab</label></li>
<li><label for="id_checkbox_field_1"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="checkbox_field" value="598" id="id_checkbox_field_1" /> phy lab</label></li>
<li><label for="id_checkbox_field_2"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="checkbox_field" value="599" id="id_checkbox_field_2" /> chem lab</label></li>
</ul>
```

I want to replace the `<ul>` and `<li>` tag with `<div class="class-name">`

Need help.

Comment: MY_CHOICES=((type.id, type.title) for type in type), this will show you the id and title of the Type objects. Add in a unicode method on that class to answer what you wish to display, then just use MY_CHOICES=(type for type in type), which looks weird programatically. Also, why aren't you using ModelMultipleChoiceField?

Comment: @professorDante in template is showing correctly,i manually added a check box field and while try to save it it is not getting saved so checked and in views it is giving this error "Types object is not iteratable".But as per django doc 1.4 if we iterate form.fieldname,it should display the check box with value along with the added div.Now i am using django 1.4.1 then why it is not supported in my application

Answer (score 6):

Why not use the power of Django template tags ?

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
register = template.Library()


@register.filter("as_div")
def as_div(form):
    form_as_div = form.as_ul().replace("<ul", "<div").replace("</ul", "</div")
    form_as_div = form_as_div.replace("<li", "<div").replace("</li", "</div")
    return mark_safe(form_as_div)
```

Put that in a template tag and then do this simply in your template

```
{% load ad_div %}

{# some Code #}

{{ form|as_div }}

{# some other code #}
```

============================

## Other approach (Better Cleaner)

Another approach would be to extend django forms model

as follows

```
from django.forms.forms import BaseForm

Class AsDiv(BaseForm):

def as_div(self):
        return self._html_output(
            normal_row = u'<div%(html_class_attr)s>%(errors)s%(label)s %(field)s%(help_text)s</div>',
            error_row = u'<div>%s</div>',
            row_ender = '</div>',
            help_text_html = u' <span class="helptext">%s</span>',
            errors_on_separate_row = False)
```

Then you could just do this is your template

```
{{ form.as_div }}
```

Comment: Your solution looks very simple i am going to try this.In template tag approach instead of form i should use my form name right in my case form is replaced by "TypeSelectionForm" is it correct.

Comment: Yeah you have to replace that with what ever variable name is holding your form object

Comment: your templatetag solution is working fine,i can able to apply common class to all div.I need one more help,i need to provide a button to all form field inside the div.Each div have a button.Is it possible to do here.Thanks.

Comment: You can or can't? I didn't understand. Do you want to add a different class to each div or the same class to all of them.

If different then what is the criteria that defines which div takes which class

Comment: I am able to apply same class to all div,what i am asking is is it possible to include/add a input button to that div.

Comment: Yes you can but you wont be able to pick up any values from these inputs 

Just change this 
    `normal_row = u'<div%(html_class_attr)s>%(errors)s%(label)s %(field)s%(help_text)s</div>'`

to be 

    `normal_row = u'<div%(html_class_attr)s>%(errors)s%(label)s [ADD YOU INPUT HERE]%(field)s%(help_text)s</div>'`

Comment: Thanks bhappy.Good to see your comments.Need one more clarification if i entends the django model form(your better cleaner approach) what i suggest to do is i need to paste all codes in a file called widget.py and i need to import that file in forms.py.Is it correct.Or i can keep this code directly in forms.py.

Comment: Have that code in any name you want for consistency just call it asdiv.py and then save that any where you want in the project (make sure there is an __ init __.py file in the same folder where you save it, if there is no init file just create an empty file and name it that). Then if you need to use that in you templates you have to do use it as directed above `{{ form.as_div }}`

Comment: Partially your answer supported my needs.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect):

> *New in Django 1.4.*
>
> For more granular control over the generated markup, you can loop over
>   the radio buttons in the template. Assuming a form `myform` with a
>   field `beatles` that uses a `RadioSelect` as its widget:
>
> ```
> {% for radio in myform.beatles %}
> <div class="myradio">
>     {{ radio }}
> </div>
> {% endfor %}
> ```

In your template, you should have this:

```
{% for radio in types.checkbox_field %}
   <input style="margin: 8px -3px;float: left;" type="button" class="delete_types" id="delete_name"/>{{ radio }}
{% endfor %}
```

You should also use a [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield):

```
class TypeSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    checkbox_field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label="",
                                                    queryset=Types.objects.none(),
                                                    required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = kwargs.pop('queryset')
        super(TypeSelectionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['checkbox_field'].queryset = qs
```

Initiate it like this from your view:

```
def types(method):
    """"""""""""
    qs = Types.objects.filter(parent_type_id=type_id,is_active=True)
    types = TypeSelectionForm(queryset=qs)
    return render(request,'types.html',{'types':'types'})
```

Comment: I tried this i am getting this error "__init__() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)" indicating this line in views.py "types = TypeSelectionForm(queryset=qs)". may i know how to solve this.

Comment: Sorry to say as this is not rendering the given image against all check box instead only one image is displaying.I had added my current output in the question,i want to add that round image to all the check box field created dynamically.Please help me in doing this.

Comment: If you just copy pasted the template code then it won't work; can you update the code you are using?

Comment: From doc i corrected that,i am able to see the image for all check box added but it is not displaying the check box and their label.I updated my current output in question.Could you please tell me what could be the problem.

Comment: Remove `.field.choices`.

Comment: But as per django doc 1.4 if we iterate form.fieldname,it should display the check box with value along with the added div.Now i am using django 1.4.1 then why it is not supported in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Widgets take an attrs attribute, which should add the attribute to each input. Try this:

```
checkbox_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'my-image-class', }), label="", required=False)
```

**UPDATE:**

So it looks like the granular approach mentioned above only works for radio button widgets. But what you want is actually very simple. Just output your checkboxes as normal:

```
{% for field in types.checkbox_field %}                                 
 {{field}}
{% endfor %}
```

This will output your list of checkboxes as you need. Then just use a little CSS to style the background image of each list item:

```
form ul li {
background:url("<my-image>") no-repeat center;
width:20px;
height:20px;
```

}

**UPDATE**

If you want to render the checkboxes differently, you need a custom widget class, as that's the widgets job. Something like this will get you going. I'd personally use the attrs option on the widget to add in a class, but I've hard coded it here to show you that what you ask is possible, just not pretty:

```
class CheckboxDivSelectMultiple(CheckboxSelectMultiple):
'''renders the checkboxes as divs with a hard coded class'''

def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
    if value is None: value = []
    has_id = attrs and 'id' in attrs
    final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
    output = [u'<div>']
    # Normalize to strings
    str_values = set([force_unicode(v) for v in value])
    for i, (option_value, option_label) in enumerate(chain(self.choices, choices)):
        # If an ID attribute was given, add a numeric index as a suffix,
        # so that the checkboxes don't all have the same ID attribute.
        if has_id:
            final_attrs = dict(final_attrs, id='%s_%s' % (attrs['id'], i))
            label_for = u' for="%s"' % final_attrs['id']
        else:
            label_for = ''

        cb = CheckboxInput(final_attrs, check_test=lambda value: value in str_values)
        option_value = force_unicode(option_value)
        rendered_cb = cb.render(name, option_value)
        option_label = conditional_escape(force_unicode(option_label))
        output.append(u'<div class="%s"><label%s>%s %s</label></div>' % ('new-class', label_for, rendered_cb, option_label))
    output.append(u'</div>')
    return mark_safe(u'\n'.join(output))
```

use it in your form:

```
checkbox_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxDivSelectMultiple(), label="", required=False)
```

Comment: This is not working,this adds the css class to that check box.

Comment: I'm confused - isn't that what you need? Can you show the markup this is generating?

Comment: Hai,it is generating the field without check box.from this doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect now the image is displaying but the field are displayed with their id.Please see my current output in question.Please see "Output i am getting" in question that type with all checkbox field with image is required.

Comment: Because you aren't printing the full checkbox in your template, you're printing this: {% for field in types.checkbox_field.field.choices %}. Just use {%for field in types %}{{field}}{%endfor%}

Comment: Your solution is good.Again sorry for asking one more doubt,my application flow is on clicking that image a hidden button comes to display.Is it possible with the solution now you given.If so please update your answer.Now i understand the actual requirement and updated the question with clear requirement.Sorry for not giving the proper requirement.

Comment: do i need to write the CheckboxDivSelectMultiple method inviews.py.Now i placed in forms.py and it is giving name error "name 'CheckboxSelectMultiple' is not defined"

Comment: Python 101 - import declarations. I'm not handholding you through these types of errors!

Comment: Hi i changed CheckboxSelectMultiple' to forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple' and the previous error was solved.Now a new error "Tried followup_setting in module setting.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'CheckboxDivSelectMultiple'" i know which line the error is,any rough idea what could be the issue.

Comment: These are all just import errors - put the widget in a file called widgets.py, place it in your app, and import the class CheckboxDivSelectMultiple where you make the form, probably in forms.py.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to @bhappy 's solution. The overall solution is to define a custom as_div method and use it as a template filter in your templates. Have a look at this django snippets post: [Custom Form Example: Forms for Bootstrap Html - CSS Toolkit](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2631/)